# Is it possible to expand items in VS Code's Explorer View recursively when using its "Filter on Type" feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to filter items in the Explorer tab of VS Code without needing to expand the folders manually first?

So if I started with a collapsed folder and filtering 'test' for example I'd want this:

[image: Expanded Folder showing expanded folder structure]

Instead of this:

[image: Collapsed folder]

Comment: you can use `Ctrl+P` and then `test`

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'm doing it now, but it means that I have to do it multiple times if I need to open multiple files.

Comment: It's also useful to only see certain files in your file explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to filter items in the Explorer tab of VS Code without needing to expand the folders manually first?

At the time of this writing? No. See [Explorer: resolve all folders before filtering #66971](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66971).

You can give the issue ticket a thumbs up reaction to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress. [Please refrain from making noisy "+1" or "bump" comments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions).

Note that if all you care about is searching for a file in your workspace(s), you can use [the Quick Open feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation) instead.

---

Some various tools that may be of help in the meantime (many of these suggested or created by various users / VS Code community members (whom I am not affiliated with)):

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sandipchitale.revealfolder
- Using [the Quick Open feature of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation) instead.
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66971#issuecomment-1238452087 <sup><sub>(I'm not really a fan of this one or the full way it's presented on its GitHub page, but I'm still linking to it just to be fair)</sub></sup>
- Someone has listed a possible workaround [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66971#issuecomment-1973062439), but I haven't verified it.

Also related:

- [How can I expand all files in VS Code's Explorer View?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76078594/11107541)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9456#issuecomment-456740075

For your reference / learning purposes, the above issue tickets were found by googling "`vscode explorer recursively expand`" and clicking through related issue ticket links in the top search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search feature as a workaround:

1. open search
2. search for the regex expression .* (matches everything)
3. set *files to include* to the filename you want to be displayed
4. view results as tree
5. collapse all findings

In my case, I want all Dockerfiles to be displayed:

[image]

Yes. The display of the file content, opened from the search result, is terrible, because the regex marks everything :-)