# VS Code sidebar filter no longer shows up upon typing starting in version 1.70

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code version 1.70. My OS is Fedora.

The sidebar filter worked fine, but from yesterday it doesn't show up on typing. I need help with getting it back.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[VS Code 1.70 updated the tree view searching to use `ctrl+f`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_tree-find-control). Note that at the time of this writing, there are [still known issues that have yet to be fixed with this change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67596724/11107541).

The "Filter on Type" feature is not *totally* gone. When you type without opening up the find input in the Explorer panel, VS Code will still change the *active* tree list item to be the one that is like what you typed though, and you can also still navigate the active tree item with arrow keys. Note that [VS Code 1.78 had a regression with this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76199778/11107541).

If anyone knows that it is possible to go back to the old behaviour (and how), you are very welcome to edit this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Several times I encountered this issue. I used to reinstall the VS code and Fix that. Secondly, Re-open the vs code. Please check out the preferences/settings if there're any settings changed or not.
If none of them works you may follow the link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface