# Why can't I type in VS Code 1.78.0's Explorer View to auto focus matching items?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Previously, in VS Code's file explorer panel, I was able to type a word say "lib", the highlighted file would automatically jump to a file with that name.

But my latest VS Code loses that ability. When typing characters while focusing on the file explorer view, the highlight does not move at all.

Is there a setting to turn this feature on and off? I can't find exactly this setting anywhere.

I tried typing characters while focusing on the file explorer view, the highlighted file do not change at all.

```
Version: 1.78.0 (user setup)
Commit: 252e5463d60e63238250799aef7375787f68b4ee
Date: 2023-05-03T20:09:00.748Z
Electron: 22.4.8
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: Yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Likely Cause

This sounds like this regression in VS Code 1.78: [First-letter navigation in explorer tree views no longer works
#179528](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179528)

The regression is confirmed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179528#issuecomment-1534955113) to be caused by the [refactor keybinding resolver #178699](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/178699) pull request.

#### Solutions for the above Problem

- A fix is apparently ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179528#issuecomment-1535258349)) released in the Insiders version of VS Code, which you can install [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).
- The issue ticket is marked as being in the [April 2023 Recovery 2 milestone](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/231) at the time of this writing, which I think means you can also wait for the next next minor release of VS Code 1.78.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues 1.78 explorer type search`", which led to [this issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181738), which is closed as a duplicate of the one I showed.