# How to bring back the type to search feature from VS Code 1.67.1?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the old version of VS Code, I can click on any file name to start a search, but now it requires a click and ctrl+f. If I use ctrl+shift+p, I need to press backspace then. Is there any method that allows opening a file in the workspace by file name triggered only by one action?

[the file search panel in VS Code now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfe80.png)
This is the feature I refer to. I think it is inconvenient compared to older version.

Comment: what does ctrl+shift+p (command palette) have to do with the Explorer search widget? Why do you need to press backspace? If you want Quick Open, then use `ctrl+p`.

Comment: what do you mean by "click on any file name to start a search"? I have never heard of such a feature in VS Code. And why do you need to click on a file to open the Explorer search widget? Do you mean you need to focus the Explorer View first before pressing `ctrl+f`? Because you can focus the Explorer View without clicking a file (Ex. the `Explorer: Focus on Folders View`, which you can bind to a keyboard shortcut if you want).

Comment: ok... upon further reading, I think I understand what you are talking about, but you probably could have done a better job at explaining, and I'm not even 100% sure I understand you right now.

Comment: actually, now, colour me royally confused. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73296706/11107541. VS Code didn't switch to using `ctrl+f` for filtering in the Explorer View until version 1.70, so the behaviour you want should already be like how you want it in 1.67... What's going on? What you're saying doesn't make sense / add up.

Comment: or when you say "bring back feature **in**", do you really mean "bring back feature **from**"? There's a big difference. The first is asking to have that feature in version 1.67, the second is to have a feature that is in 1.67 back in versions newer than 1.67.

Comment: Oh I'm dumb and didn't know ctrl+p does the same thing (occupied by another software so I never used it). Sorry for my poor English, I do mean **from** instead of **in**.