# How can I expand all files in VS Code's Explorer View?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VS Code File Explorer View has a "Collapse All" button but no "Expand All" button, if fact I don't see a way to expand all directories recursively as a single operation at all (The command palette shows a "Collapse All Folders" command, but no "Expand All Folders" command)

I generally wouldn't use a fully expanded tree but it's the only way I know to see all files that match when a filename filter is applied to the tree view without manually expanding every subdirectory (which only seem to be evaluated against the filter expression as you expand them).

I'm using version: 1.77.3 (Universal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a way to expand all directories recursively as a single operation

No, I don't know of such a feature. And I see this as an XY problem, given that you said

> it's the only way I know to see all files that match when a filename filter is applied to the tree view without manually expanding every subdirectory (which only seem to be evaluated against the filter expression as you expand them).

A quick google of "`github vscode issues explorer search collapsed folders`" turns up the following issue tickets:

- [Explorer search is useless with collapsed folders #82941](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/82941)
- [Please make it so that the search function in the file explorer descends into closed folders #159909](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/159909)
- [Explorer filter fails to find items in folders that have never been expanded in the current session #137555](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137555)
- [Improvement Request: Explorer Find should automatically unfold folders
  #167181](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167181)

which are all closed as a duplicate of [Explorer: resolve all folders before filtering #66971](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66971). Its current milestone at the time of this writing is "[On Deck](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/27)". Subscribe to the issue ticket to get notified of updates and discussion. <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

Someone has listed a possible workaround [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66971#issuecomment-1973062439), but I haven't verified it.

Comment: Not exactly an XY problem, because the ticket you've pointed to was opened in 2019, and while it **should** address the underlying issue, the fact that it still isn't implemented (see one comment near the end listing the whys) is a sign that this isn't coming anytime soon.

Answer (score -4):

Type "*" in the search bar (above the file hierarchy) and you will see everything expanded.

Here is an example.

[image]

Comment: cannot repro. what search bar? Explorer find?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the question is about VS Code. NOT Visual Studio.

Comment: isnt that the same thing

Comment: no. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio