# VS Code preview folder in explorer by searching path

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to open a preview of a folder in the explorer by searching for its path? E.g. suppose my repo is highly nested and I know I want to open folder `c` which is under `a/b`, is there a way to enter `a/b/c` and have it preview as if I manually opened `a`, manually opened `b`, and manually opened `c`?

Comment: are you running up against this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76078717/11107541 (see the issue tickets in my answer post there)